# GeoServer has a strange behaviour when using authkey

Tags: geoserver, docker

I have the following problem and I don't understand if this is normal and what happens behind the scenes:

I have setup GeoServer 2.23.2 with authkey using docker and added a role to a workspace in order to secure it. If I access the next URLs in this order:

https://geoserver.acme.local/geoserver/my_wokspace/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=my_wokspace%3A55_57_3857%09&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&authkey=BAD_KEY&upperCase=false&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=2865471.316354688,5733388.617614502,2866082.812580969,5734000.113840783

HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden (BAD KEY)

https://geoserver.acme.local/geoserver/my_wokspace/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=my_wokspace%3A55_57_3857%09&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&authkey=GOOD_KEY&upperCase=false&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=2865471.316354688,5733388.617614502,2866082.812580969,5734000.113840783

Tile returned (GOOD KEY)

https://geoserver.acme.local/geoserver/my_wokspace/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=my_wokspace%3A55_57_3857%09&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&authkey=BAD_KEY&upperCase=false&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=2865471.316354688,5733388.617614502,2866082.812580969,5734000.113840783

HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden (BAD KEY)

https://geoserver.acme.local/geoserver/

https://geoserver.acme.local/geoserver/my_wokspace/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=my_wokspace%3A55_57_3857%09&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&authkey=GOOD_KEY&upperCase=false&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=2865471.316354688,5733388.617614502,2866082.812580969,5734000.113840783

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found (GOOD KEY) - This should return the tile, exactly as the 2nd URL because they are the same but it seems that there is a cache/session problem?!

Now I'm getting 404s until I close the browser and all is working as before. Same happens in postman.